# Getting an error in Paypal MPL Library:invalid shiping id entered(ANDROID_529037)

Tags: android, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

[image][image]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMbOM.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxqK7.png`enter code here`

here is my code

```
private void paypalbtnclick(String s3, String s2, String s1, String s) {
    // configuring accounts
    PayPalReceiverDetails receiver0,receiver1;
    receiver0= new PayPalReceiverDetails();
    receiver0.setRecipient(s3);
    receiver0.setSubtotal(new BigDecimal(s2));
    receiver1= new PayPalReceiverDetails();
    receiver1.setRecipient(s1);
    receiver1.setSubtotal(new BigDecimal(s));
    PayPalAdvancedPayment advPayment= new PayPalAdvancedPayment();
    advPayment.setCurrencyType("USD");
    advPayment.getReceivers().add(receiver0);
    advPayment.getReceivers().add(receiver1);
    advPayment.setMerchantName("PlayAt");
    Intent payPalIntent = PayPal.getInstance().checkout(advPayment,this);
    this.startActivityForResult(payPalIntent,PAYPAL_RESPONSE);
}
```

Comment: I have got the solution... Problen is in sandbox accounts

Comment: could you provide detail about your issue. I'm getting crashed in paypal intent android

Comment: @Jatin.. It was solved. Everything was okay in code. I had issue in sandbox accounts. I had save same merchant name as project name.